# Get PHP variable value via Ajax with variable name as parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I realise similar questions have come up a few times, but I can't seem to find one that will help with what I am trying to do.

We have a config.php file which is basically a list of variables that a user sets, along with their values, eg:

```
$OUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'test@test.com';
$OUR_WEBSITE       = 'www.test.com';
```

Just like all the other users we want to transfer a PHP value via Javascript.

We have a way of doing this already, via ajax - but it is not as flexible as we would like as each variable needs a custom script / php page:

**Part 1 - javascript (jquery)**

```
$.get("/getConfig_email.php", function(email){
    alert(email);
});
```

**part 2: getConfig_email.php**

```
<?php
echo $OUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_VALUE;
?>
```

**The question:**

Is there a way that PHP can use a string as a variable name? ie. What I want to do is this:

**Part 1 - javascript (jquery)**

```
$.get("/getConfig.php?name=OUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_VALUE", function(email){
    alert(email);
});
```

**part 2: getConfig.php**

```
<?php
$var_name = $_GET['name'];

//some magic here to turn the name of the variable 
//in to the actual variable - a bit like a reverse extract

echo $var_name.value;
?>
```

What do you think? Is this possible somehow - I'm hoping there is just a php command that can do this for me!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible via [**`variable variables`**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
echo $$var_name;
```

However, this is unwise since you are taking user input and possibly the user can get values of internal variables that are supposed to be hidden.

Comment: Ah - this could be exactly what we are after. I had read the php page on this but didnt really get how to use them.

So in the example I gave - I would just:

`$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $$name;`

Does that look right?

Comment: Obviously will do what we can to deal with security issues, such as naming and checking the variables names that are allowed to be collected or something.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the better option will be to set config variables inside an array:

```
$CFG = array(
    'OUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS' => 'test@test.com',
    'OUR_WEBSITE' => 'www.test.com'
);
```

And pick up them with:

```
$var_name = $_GET['name'];
echo isset($CFG[$var_name]) ? $CFG[$var_name] : "";
```

Otherwise, it might be a real security problem of your script.

Comment: Yep... that was what I thought when I first wanted to do this... In hindsight - it is definitely what we would have done. As it is, there is just a page where users can set direct variables.

This script will only be usable with logged in users - (I didnt paste the whole thing above) and there are other security checks.

Comment: Well, then the solution of @mellamokb will work in your case. So use `$var_name = $_GET['name']; echo $$var_name;`. But anyway try to avoid such "dirty hacks" in your future projects :)

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary with all your config variables and use it to look up a variable by name

Comment: Alas, we are way too far down the road to do this. New projects all work in this way.