# Detect all uppercase variables in PHP project (and replace with something else)

Tags: php, search, variables, text, uppercase

Firstly - some background. We have a config.php file which lists several variables and settings in this format:

```
$MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS    = 'test@test.com';
$MY_WEBSITE          = 'www.test.com';
$SOMETHING_ELSE      = 'foobar';
```

I would like to replace them with more sensible (and secure) names as part of an array, throughout the entire PHP project. Mostly so we can do this more securely: [Get PHP variable value via Ajax with variable name as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364940/get-php-variable-value-via-ajax-with-variable-name-as-parameter/10364987#10364987)

We have also forgotten some of these variables names, so that they are used throughout the project, but possibly not documented - hence doing a search one-by-one will prove difficult.

Is there a way I can search the php files for any values that start with a dollar sign ($) and then are made up of only upper case letters and possibly underscores?

```
$MY_SETTING_NAME
```

We could then either build a list and update manually, or build some kind of script to replace things with a more sensible way of working:

```
$CONFIG['MY_SETTING_NAME']
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can do a regex text search on your php scripts in your IDE or code editor. `/\$([A-Z0-9_]+)\s?=)/` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_defined_vars function which will return all variables as array.

Please look at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) website for example

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this will need to be done on a non-running application (ie. in the source code). I think the Regex answer above should do the trick.